# ActionBar in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a responsive website using Bootstrap. When the site is in mobile mode, I would like a bar fixed across the bottom to appear. I would like that bar to have a single button in it. Is there a way to fix a bar across the bottom of the screen when a Bootstrap site is in mobile mode? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Sticky footer examples:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

If you only want it visible in mobile mode look into the following css classes:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities